# jQuery seamless carousel

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-plugins

I need a jQuery plugin for infinite carousel that's seamless and indicates location.

I tried CorouFredSel but after sliding to another slide this carousel creates a blank space for a while.

Comment: I think that ColorBox does a carousel plugin. You might want to try them out.

Answer (score 4):

I've always been a fan of [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/)

Comment: The circular carousel would be particularly useful to @Tomáš Mihalička
http://sorgalla.com/projects/jcarousel/examples/static_circular.html

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Orbit](http://www.zurb.com/playground/orbit-jquery-image-slider) for a lightweight semantic-HTML slider:

```
<div id="featured"> 
  <img src="overflow.jpg" />
  <img src="captions.jpg" />
  <img src="features.jpg" />
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(window).load(function() {
    $('#featured').orbit();
  });
</script>
```